# Horizontal align the thumbnail in a jQuery mobile listview

Tags: css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm new working with listviews in jQuery mobile.

The CSS code i'm using to override the default used with jQuery mobile is:

```
<style type="text/css">
.has-odd-thumb li a {
padding-left: 90px !important;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.thumbContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbContainer img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 80px;
}
</style>
```

This is to make my non-squared images fit correctly when they are thumbnails in the different items in my list.

This is the code to my list (simplified for quick reference):

```
<ul id="lista" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." data-inset="true" class="has-odd-thumb">
<li><a href="#" id="1" class="item-lista">
<div class="thumbContainer">
<img src="img/test.jpg">
</div>
<h2><i>Item</i></h2>
<p>Description text</p>
</a></li></ul>
```

Until now everything works fine, I have the images fitted inside the 80px square thumbnail, but my problem is if the image is wider (a rectangle) it doesn't appear centered in the square space of the thumbnail. It appear aligned to the left.
**How can I make the image centered in that square space?**

Thanks

**EDITED:**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile thumbnail image alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398492/jquery-mobile-thumbnail-image-alignment)

Comment: It's not a dupplicate because that post is when you have images smaller that 80px square. In my case the images are larger than this, and appear fitted in the space but aligned to the left. I want it centered. I've used that solution and doesn't solve my problem :S

Comment: ok. So if the images are larger, what is to happen exactly? Should they shrink to fit? Should they bleed? Should they be cropped?

Comment: They have to appear centered in the square space. They already shrink to fit entirely in the square, but inside the image is not centered, it's aligned to the left. I'll post an image illustrating this for clarity...

Comment: They are centered with the code you've given. http://jsfiddle.net/vCv7L/

Comment: Do you want the image to cover the container (cropped), or be contained within it (letterbox)?

Comment: Cropped. I've uploaded my question with an image for better understanding...

Comment: @Popnoodles I don't know why I can make it work correctly. Maybe someting with the jQuery mobile framework?

Comment: If you will never have portrait images my second answer will crop and center the landscape ones. Otherwise the only options I can think of are background image or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xDq2E/)

```
.thumbContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbContainer img {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 80px;
}
```

This answer does not cover with portrait rectangles... which is why I'd recommend the background image or Javascript methods.

Comment: Nope, my bad. I should stop answering questions on here, I'm too tired. XD

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy CSS fix. Let me know if you'd like a lil Javascript to loop over and resize the images to fit nicely. :)

Comment: Hehehe. Good rest! Drink a beer or something. You deserve it!

Comment: If you have the time and energy it will be most welcome!

Comment: Will do first thing tomorrow. Need sleep (now 1am here). :)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mh5j/)**

As promised here is some simple JQuery to cover your thumbnail with the correct ratios & center them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Find thumbnail containers
    $('.thumbContainer').each(function () {
        // Get current thumbnail container
        var thumb = $(this);
        // Get current thumbnail image
        var img = thumb.children('img');
        // Calculate image ratio
        var ratio = img.innerWidth() / img.innerHeight();
        var newW, newH;
        // Calculate new width & height
        if (ratio >= 1) {
            newH = thumb.innerHeight();
            newW = newH * ratio;
        } else {
            newW = thumb.innerWidth();
            newH = newW / ratio;
        }
        // Apply new width & height
        img.width(newW);
        img.height(newH);
        // Calculate and apply offsets  
        // You can replace thumb.outerHeight / width with exact values if you want
        img.css('top', (thumb.outerHeight() - newH) / 2);
        img.css('left', (thumb.outerWidth() - newW) / 2);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try using this :)

Comment: It's good but when I apply that to the listview it doesn't fill all the container. It shows a white space below (not totally square). I don't know why because in the demo works perfectly. It's possible to zoom in a little bit the images? It's almost perfect! Otherwise i'll keep the old solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you using the same styles as in my demo? Make sure you take out the max-height and margin auto. :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think your issues may have been due to having a border / padding so I changed thumb.innerWidth to outerWidth. You can however, as I've now added in a comment, swap these out for exact values e.g. 80.

Answer (score -2):

You could set the images as background images and use:

```
background-size: cover;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

...or calculate the exact scale with some Javascript.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like some Javascript and I could write a small example when I have some time. :)

Comment: But I have to set one by one all the images in this way? I have tons of images!