# How do I get background (cover) images to resize and fit browser width w/ fullpage.js?

Tags: css, resize, background-image, fullpage.js

I hope you can help me out, I'm stuck with this problem.

Example here: http://myko.dk/pegasus/index.html (work in progress)

I'd like to make the background images automatically resize to fit browser width. Now, as you can see, the image is cropped when resizing. I'm still learning to code, I might have messed up the css, and working with fullpage.js has been confusing as well.

Actually, I thought "background-size:cover" would automatically resize - would anyone care to elaborate on that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a css problem...

Comment: Several answers (css & js) that may be useful to you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795147/horizontal-align-the-thumbnail-in-a-jquery-mobile-listview/23795223#23795223

Answer (score 1):

`background-size:cover` is the correct way to do this.

Your implementation simply has a few problems:

- You have multiple background images on the same element (the photo and the logo).  It is on this element that you should use `cover` (as you are doing) so you need the logo to be on a different element (otherwise it will resize as well)
- Where you are currently setting `background-size: cover;` is getting overridden by your `background:` property.  You can fix this by either including the `background-resize` immediately after the `background:` or by changing you current `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: cover !important;`
- You should not need to use js for this unless you need good backwards browser support (older than IE 9).

For more info see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility).